# Edit element of the list with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I tried to find out myself how to pass value of key to the reducer but without succes. My intention is to edit on button the chosen element. For now I cant catch id of element and all the elements are changing. Could somebody tell me how it works?

my code is here:
for the container:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onEditComponent: (component, id) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.EDIT_COMPONENT, data: {componentToReducer: component, ind: id}})
  }
}
```

and for reducer:

```
case actionTypes.EDIT_COMPONENT:
      return {
       ...state,
       components: state.components.map((component,i) =>  i === action.data.ind ?
       {...component, co: action.data.componentToReducer} : component
     )
    };
```

There is also a code when I am building a structure html:

```
  render() {
    const edit =  this.props.compons.map((comp, index) =>(
        <div
        key={comp.id}>
          <EditComponent
            clicked={this.props.onEditComponent}/>
        </div>
      ));

    return (
      <div>
        <AddComponent
          click={this.props.onAddComponent}
        />

          {
            this.props.compons.map((component)=>(
          <div key={component.id}
          >
            <p
            onClick={this.showTrue}
            className={classes.Component}>{component.co}
            </p>
            <button
            onClick={()=>this.props.onDeleteComponent(component.id)}>
              Delete component
            </button>
          </div>
            ))
          }
          {this.state.show ? edit : null}

      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have a solution. EditComponent must be connected with reducer at state (mapStateToProps), and then I can pass it to this reducer to dispatch action and finally edit element from list. Thank you for attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the id and the component to onEditComponent action, pass it on to the EditComponent

```
const edit =  this.props.compons.map((comp, index) =>(
    <div
    key={comp.id}>
      <EditComponent
        comp ={comp}
        clicked={this.props.onEditComponent}/>
    </div>
  ));
```

and inside EditComponent when you click on edit, you would write

```
handleClick= () => {
   this.props.clicked(this.props.comp, this.props.comp.id)
}
```

Comment: yes, you had partially right. I had to pass id but not with this.props.comp.id. Instead of this I had to connect EditComponent with state from reducer and pass it as props. Simple but for begginer like me it was hard to understand.